# How would one go about proving an infinite set is a set?

Tags: set-theory

Say you wanted to prove the set Z such that Z = $\{\phi, \{\phi\}, \{\{\phi\}\}, ... \}$ is a set. We could construct each element of z using the pair axiom or the power set axiom (I think) but how would we go about proving it infinitely?

Comment: Well. You need axioms. What axioms are you using? Infinity? Replacement?

Comment: Any of the ZFC axioms. I’m guessing the axiom of infinity is required but I’m not sure where to start with this.

Answer (score 3):

**Step I:** Prove that $\omega$ is a set, where $\omega$ is the smallest inductive set, or the closure of $\{\varnothing\}$ under the successor operator ($x\mapsto x\cup\{x\}$).

**Step II:** Prove the recursion theorem. Namely, you can define a function on $\omega$ by specifying what it is doing for $0$, and how to define the successor steps. Replacement and Union are your friends for this proof.

**Step III:** Use the recursion theorem. Clearly $F(0)=\varnothing$, how would you define $F(n+1)$?

**Step IV:** The range of a function is a set.

---

Alternatively, prove Step I and use the specific instance of the recursion theorem and find a formula such that $\varphi(n,x)$ holds if and only if $x$ is the $n$th iteration of taking a singleton with $\varphi(\varnothing,\varnothing)$. Then apply Replacement.